# PCRE2 regular expression with optional ending character always matches the optional ending character

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a PCRE2 expression that reads a username from some logs.
In the logs, the username might optionally be in brackets.
I need to get the username via the regex, without the brackets of course.

Example logs:

```
msg_id="1100-0005" Authentication of Firewall user [someuser@somehost] from fe80::badd:cafe was rejected, password is incorrect
msg_id="5000-0001" WebUI User anotheruser@anotherhost from 10.0.0.2 log in attempt was rejected - invalid credentials.
```

The regex I came up with (where group 3 should be the username):

```
msg_id="[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"\s(Authentication of)?\s?(.*\s[Uu]ser)\s\[?(\S+)\]?\s
```

So far, I get `someuser@somehost]` for the first log and `anotheruser@anotherhost` for the second log.
Is there a way I can get rid of the ending bracket without using non-greedy option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
msg_id="[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"(?:\s+Authentication of)?\s+(.*?\s[Uu]ser)\s\[?([^\[\]\s]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLqeUA/2). *Details*:

- `msg_id="` - a literal string
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{4}` - four hex chars
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{4}` - four hex chars
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?:\s+Authentication of)?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces and then `Authentication of` string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?\s[Uu]ser)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then a whitespace and `User` or `user`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\[?` - an optional `[` char
- `([^\[\]\s]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `]`, `[` and whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. Just removed the '+' modifier from the \s since it must match exactly one space. At the end, I didn't know that [^chars] = no chars in the list, whereas ^ usually stands for begin.